# What is "generic"?

Tags: differential-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

What does the term *"generic"* mean for a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Please give me the definition of *"$M$ is generic"* , where $M$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I have looked at the introduction of the [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3788.pdf). There may be no explanation of the definition of the term "generic".

Comment: I am interested in the phrase "hypersurface in $\Bbb R^3$". Is that something different from a surface, or are we just in a setting where higher dimension objects occur frequently, so the term is used to be consistent?

Comment: @Arthur: The term hyper- is used to emphasize that we care about the way it sits inside $\Bbb R^3$, as much or more than the underlying geometric object of the surface itself.

Comment: If you are interested in the term "hypersurface," why is your  question about the word "generic?" This is why having actual text which uses the terminology, in a sentence, is vital to help you. Help us help you.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I wondered why "hypersurface" was used, but I did not post the main question (comments made by the OP are marked as such, but it might be difficult to see, depending on your monitor).

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_property#Definitions:_topology

Comment: One meaning of "generic" is "except on a set of measure zero". Another is "except on a meager set", where "meager" means "countable union of nowhere dense sets". Other usages are usually similar in spirit; for instance, generically a function which attains its minimum does so in the interior, not on the boundary (a useful situation in large deviation theory).

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the link. Hypersurface describes submanifolds of codimension 1. So a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a 2 dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I don't know if the term "generic" makes sense in higher dimensional settings.

Comment: @Arthur The term hypersurfaces is used is properly because in most of the paper the authors works with hypersurfaces in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ and specialize to $\mathbb R^3$ only in one or two sections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What it is not**: If you read the whole paper, you will understand that the term "generic" is used only in a non-rigorous way. Definitely not the one we see in differential topology/algebraic geometry.

**What it is**: In the paper they introduced the notion of entropy $\lambda$ of an immersion. One important property is that if $\{\Sigma_t\}$ is the mean curvature flow starting at $\Sigma$, then $\lambda(\Sigma_t)$ is nonincreasing in $t$. When $\{\Sigma_t\}$ becomes singular at time $T$ and $S$ is a self-shrinker which models the singularity, then we also have 
$$\lambda (S)\le \lim_{t\to T} \lambda(\Sigma_t),$$
(mainly because $\lambda$ is translation and scaling invariant). This is simple yet profound as now we have a quantity which is momotonic along the flow, and the monotonicity actually passes to the "limit" as $t\to T$, when the flow is no longer smooth.

Now they ask: Can we slightly perturb $\Sigma_t$ to a new $\hat \Sigma$ for some $t<T$ closed to $T$, so that $\lambda (\hat \Sigma)<\lambda (S)$ (Remark: In some nice case a rescaling of $\Sigma_{t}$ is closed to $S$, so we are looking for a hypersurface closed to $S$)? If that can be done, then we restart the flow at $\hat \Sigma$:

$$ \Sigma \overset{flow}{\to } \Sigma_{t_0} \overset{perturb}{\to } \hat \Sigma \to \text{flow again}$$

The point is that when in the restart flow $\hat \Sigma_t$ hits a singularity which is modeled by a self-shrinker $\hat S$, **this $\hat S$ cannot be $S$ as $\lambda (\hat S) <\lambda (S)$**. This could be very important as the classification of self-shrinkers seems to be a hard problem. By doing this perturbation we hope to "ignore" a lot of self-shrinkers, bypassing the hard analysis question.

Of course, whether or not such a perturbation can be done depend on the self-shrinker $S$. For example, such a perturbation cannot be found when $S = \mathbb S^n$ is the $n$-sphere in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$: If $\Sigma$ is a hypersurface which is $C^2$-closed to the sphere, then it is also convex and Huisken (JDG, 84) shows that the mean curvature flow starting at $\Sigma$ must have $\mathbb S^n$ as a singularity. In terms of monotonicity of $\lambda$, this shows that $\lambda (\Sigma) \ge \lambda (\mathbb S^n)$ for all $\Sigma$ closed to $\mathbb S^n$!

Any self-shrinker $S$ which is a local minimum of $\lambda$ (like $\mathbb S^n$) is called **entropy stable**.

One main theorem in the paper is

> **Theorem** The only entropy stable self-shrinking hypersrufaces in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ are the sphere $\mathbb S^n$ and the generalized cylinders $\mathbb R^k \times \mathbb S^{n-k}$.

Thus the authors called these **generic singularities** (so they did not define generic hypersurfaces in general).

Parts of the analysis in the paper are generalized to higher codimensions, but there isn't a result characterizing entropy stable self-shrinkers (even for compact self-shrinkers) in higher codimensions which is as precise as the above theorem in codimension one.

Comment: My question seems to be thoughtless. Sorry for making you write such a kind and detailed answer.