# Geometric meaning of $H=\langle x, \nu \rangle$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

$M$  is a $n$-dimensional smooth manifold without boundary .  $F: M \rightarrow \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is a smooth  embedding. $A$ is the second foundamental form , and $H$ is mean curvature.  $\nu$ is the normal vector.  $x$ is  position vector. If 
$$
H=\langle x, \nu \rangle           \tag{1}
$$
it is easy to see hyperplane, sphere, cylinder satisfy the equation. But I don't know whether there are other manifold satisfy this equation, especially  , manifold with negative mean curvature?

In the Huisken's Asymptotic behavior for singularities, he prove that if $M$, $n\ge 2$, is compact with nonnegative mean curvature $H$ and satisfy  (1), then $M$ is sphere of radius $\sqrt n$.

Parts of this proof is to prove  $\frac{|A|^2}{H^2}$ is constant. I don't know why he know to calculate this quantity.  Exactly , this quantity has maximum principle. Whether there are any geometric view  ?

Last, I guess the geometric essence of (1) is  the principle curvature of  must be constant or zero, right ?

Comment: Just a TeX note: `\tag{1}` sets an equation number without the hard-coded spaces. :)

Comment: Instead of $(1)$ you meant this [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature#Surfaces_in_3D_space) ?

Comment: @user1952009  This formula is  local present. But not all manifold can be presented as entire graph.  About the entire graph self shrinker in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, Lu Wang's **A Bernstein type theorem for self-similar shinkers**  asserts they are hyperplanes. But I don't find paper about the cylindic graph self-shrinker.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if $F:M\to\mathbf{R}^{m+1}$ is an isometric immersion, where $\mathrm{dim}M=m$, then you can show $\Delta F = mH_{\nu}$, where the Laplace-Beltrami operator acts on $F$ coordinatewise, and $H_{\nu}$ is the mean curvature vector of $F(M)$. Note that in the case of a sphere, $F=\mathrm{id}$ is an isometric immersion and a direct computation shows $\Delta F = 2 x$, and so by taking the dot product with respect to the unit normal you find that $H=\langle{H_\nu,\nu}\rangle=\langle x,\nu\rangle$, which is exactly the above equality.

Comment: @YousufSoliman  Could you detail talk about  how to show $\Delta F=mH_\nu$ ?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Absolutely, I posted it as an answer below since it was too long to fit in a comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A submanifold $M$ which satisfies the equation (1) is called a self-shrinker. The name comes from the fact that if $M$ is a submanifold which satisfies one, when the MCF starting at $M$ is given by

$$M_t = \sqrt{1-2t} M, t\in [0, 1/2) $$

up to diffeomorphism.

Self-shrinkers arise as a singularity model of mean curvature flow. In the type I singularity case, Huisken shows in [his paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214444099) that under the type I rescaling, the MCF converges subsequentially, locally smoothly to a submanifold satisfying the self-shrinking equation (1), see related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500229/compactness-argument-for-type-i-singularities-of-the-mean-curvature-flow).

Using again Huisken's monotonicity formula and use instead the parabolic rescaling, Ilmanen (Singularity of mean curvature flow of surfaces) and [White](https://eudml.org/doc/153922) show independently that the limit of the parabolic rescaling converges weakly to a self-shrinking flow, which is modelled by a (weak) self-shrinker.

The fact that a compact self-shrinker with $H\ge 0$ must be a sphere is generalized to the non-compact case [here](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2012/175-2/p07): if $M$ is an properly embedded self-shrinkers with $H\ge 0$, then it is either the sphere or the generalized cylinders $\mathbb S^k \times \mathbb R^{n-k}$. Actually they defined the entropy stability condition and show that all entropy stable self-shrinkers must have $H\ge 0$. See this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607148/what-is-generic) for more details.

**Examples** Indeed there are more examples than the standard one. Soon after Huisken's result, Angenent constructs using ODE the famous rotational symmetric [self-shrinking doughnuts](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~angenent/preprints/1989Gregynog/Gregynog.pdf), which is an embedded self-shrinking surface of genus one. Chopp constructs numerically [a lot more examples](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1062620999) (compact or noncompact, higher genus). Some of the example there are recently constructed using desingularization techniques [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5454), [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1407501718). It is generally believed that the classification of self-shrinkers is impossible. Colding-Minicozzi have a [compactness result](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2594) though.

The study of self-shrinkers has been the central objects. I don't think I can give a fair review here.

Answer (score 3):

To simplify some notation, I only consider the following case:
Let $M$ be an $m$-dimensional Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbf{R}^{m+1}$. Fix any vector $\vec{v}\in\mathbf{R}^{m+1}$; we will consider the real valued function $f=\langle\mathrm{id},\vec{v}\rangle$. Now fix $p\in M$ and let $\{e_1,\dots,e_m\}$ be a geodesic frame in a neighborhood of $p$. Let $\vec{N}$ be the local normal frame in the same neighborhood of $p\in\mathbf{R}^{m+1}$. Now recall that the Laplace-Beltrami operator in geodesic coordinates is given by $$\Delta g = \sum_{i=1}^{m}e_i(e_i(g)),\qquad g\in\mathscr{C}^\infty(M).$$
Note that for some vector $x\in T_pM$, that $df_p(x)=\langle x,v\rangle$. We use this to compute 
$$\Delta f = \Delta\langle\mathrm{id},\vec{v}\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{m}e_i(e_i\langle \mathrm{id},\vec{v}\rangle) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}e_i(df(e_i)) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}e_i\langle e_i,\vec{v}\rangle.$$
Now we use the compatibility of the Levi-Civita connection, $\overline\nabla$, of $\mathbf{R}^{m}$ with the Euclidean metric $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to obtain
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}e_i\langle e_i,\vec{v}\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\langle\overline\nabla_{e_i}e_i,\vec{v}\rangle + \langle e_i,\overline\nabla_{e_i}\vec{v}\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\langle\overline\nabla_{e_i}e_i,\vec{v}\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\langle\nabla_{e_i}e_i,\vec{v}\rangle+\langle \mathsf{II}(e_i,e_i),\vec{v}\rangle,$$
where $\mathsf{II}$ is the vector valued second-fundamental form. Now since $e_i$ was chosen to be a geodesic frame at $p$ we have $\nabla_{e_i}e_i(p)=0$, and so
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\langle\nabla_{e_i}e_i,\vec{v}\rangle+\langle \mathsf{II}(e_i,e_i),\vec{v}\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\langle \mathsf{II}(e_i,e_i),\vec{v}\rangle=mH\langle{N,\vec{v}}\rangle.$$
So we have shown that $$\Delta\langle{\mathrm{id},\vec{v}}\rangle=mH\langle{N,\vec{v}}\rangle.$$ Now by applying this result where $\vec{v}=x_i$ are the standard unit vectors of $\mathbf{R}^{m+1}$ we find that $$\Delta\mathrm{id}=mH\vec{N}.$$
To generalize this result to an isometrically immersed submanifold isn't much more work. This provides a very general relationship between the mean curvature vector and a submanifold of Euclidean space. In particular, we recover the relationship between the mean curvature and $\langle x,\nu\rangle$ of the sphere presented in your problem.

Comment: I like undergraduate student :)